# Single Digit Sums; "Missing Number Treated as Zero"

Tags: errors, pgfmath, random-numbers

I am trying to create a worksheet in which students practice adding single digits.

Since sums 10 or greater are more difficult, I want corresponding questions to occur more often.

This doesn't compile, though. I'm not sure why.

Is this one of those cases where I'm just missing a semi-colon or something like that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}


\newcommand{\MixedSum}
{%
%These guarantee sum>=10
\pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{int(random(1,9))}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\D}{int(10-\A)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{int(random(\D,9))}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\C}{int(\A+\B)}
%
%These are any two single digits added
\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{int(random(0,9))}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{int(random(0,9))}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Z}{int(\X+\Y)}
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{int(rand(1,2))}
\ifcase\r\relax%
 \or \(\A+\B=\C\)
 \or \(\X+\Y=\Z\)
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\MixedSum

\MixedSum

\MixedSum

\MixedSum

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`random` not `rand` and missing `%`

```
\documentclass{article}
\errorcontextlines100
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}


\newcommand{\MixedSum}
{%
%These guarantee sum>=10
\pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{int(random(1,9))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\D}{int(10-\A)}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{int(random(\D,9))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\C}{int(\A+\B)}%
%
%These are any two single digits added
\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{int(random(0,9))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{int(random(0,9))}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\Z}{int(\X+\Y)}%
%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{int(random(1,2))}%
\ifcase\r\relax
 \or \(\A+\B=\C\)%
 \or \(\X+\Y=\Z\)%
\fi
}

\begin{document}

\MixedSum

\MixedSum

\MixedSum

\MixedSum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Whoops! I understand the `rand` vs `random` part, but I still don't quite understand when I need to use `%` to end a line. How am I supposed to know that?

Comment: @WeCanLearnAnything an end of line is a space. if `\MixedSum` includes 8 spaces in its definition then if used in horizontal mode it will make a space 8 times the width of a normal inter word space. There is nothing special about `%` it just comments out the end of line.  compare `a\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{int(random(0,9))}\pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{int(random(0,9))}b` with  `a \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{int(random(0,9))} \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{int(random(0,9))} b` they do the same calculation but one typesets as `ab` and the other as `a\ \ \ b`

Answer (score 2):

Your setting of `\r` is incorrect, as it uses

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{int(rand(1,2))}
```

`rand` returns a value between -1 and 1 (with uniform distribution), so `rand(1,2)` doesn't make sense. You're probably after

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgf}
 \pgfmathsetseed{\number\pdfrandomseed}

\newcommand{\MixedSum}
  {%
  %These guarantee sum>=10
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\A}{int(random(1,9))}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\D}{int(10-\A)}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{int(random(\D,9))}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\C}{int(\A+\B)}%
  %
  %These are any two single digits added
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\X}{int(random(0,9))}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Y}{int(random(0,9))}%
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\Z}{int(\X+\Y)}%
  %
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{int(random(1,2))}%
  \ifcase\r
    \or \(\A+\B=\C\)
    \or \(\X+\Y=\Z\)
  \fi
  }

\begin{document}

\MixedSum

\MixedSum

\MixedSum

\MixedSum

\end{document}
```